# Optimal Lag for Newey West

Tags: regression, time-series, neweywest

I am currently working on my PhD thesis and was wondering how I can identify the optimal number of lags for the Newey West covariance matrix. So far, my code is

```
library(sandwich) 
library(lmtest)
library(dynlm)


Regression <- dynlm(y ~ x)
coeftest(Regression, vcov = NeweyWest(Regression, lag = NULL))
```

Since I have to compare coefficients of multiple regressions (for the same time series), I should use the same lag as well. However is there a rule of thumb or a simple method to get the lag?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: When you specify null to lag, the function automatically estimates the number of lags to use

Comment: Thank you very much Repmat. But shouldn't I use just one fixed lag for all regressions?

Comment: Well that depends on the residuals, which are likely different across model's

Comment: Exactly, but when I compare regression models, they should use the same lag, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you necessarily need to fix the lag length across regressions. Due to the different model specifications there may be slightly different amounts of autocorrelation in the residuals that you have to adjust for.

However, you can easily display the lag length employed by `NeweyWest()` and also extract it using `bwNeweyWest()`. For simple replication, let's consider the following (non-sensical because non-time-series) linear model:

```
m <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
NeweyWest(m, lag = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
## Lag truncation parameter chosen: 3 
##             (Intercept)      speed
## (Intercept)   49.250542 -3.7390757
## speed         -3.739076  0.3035406
```

The bandwidth estimation is done by `bwNeweyWest()`:

```
bwNeweyWest(m)
## [1] 3.032204
```

The lag length is just `floor()` of that.